# Flask Admin apply filters en masse as "Advanced Search"

Tags: forms, python-3.x, flask, query-string, flask-admin

I have rigged up a custom "Advanced Search" view by slightly extending the flask admin index view. This takes the user to a custom form rendered using the flask admin form rendering machinery to do most of the work.

The form is defined as follows:

```
class PaperSearchForm(FlaskForm):
    return_url = HiddenField()
    title = StringField()
    abstract = StringField()
    start_date = DateTimeField()
    end_date = DateTimeField()
    doi = StringField()
    pubmed_id = StringField()
    link =  StringField()
    journals = QuerySelectMultipleField(
        query_factory=_get_model(Journal),
    )
    authors = QuerySelectMultipleField(
        query_factory=_get_model(Author),
    )
    keywords = QuerySelectMultipleField(
        query_factory=_get_model(Keyword),
    )
    chapters = QuerySelectMultipleField(
        query_factory=_get_model(Chapter),
    )
    printed = BooleanField(default=True)
    unprinted = BooleanField(default=True)
    submit = SubmitField('Search')
```

The Advanced Search model view is defined like this:

```
from flask import flash
from flask import redirect
from flask import request
from flask_admin import BaseView
from flask_admin import expose
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_login import current_user
from .forms import PaperSearchForm


class AdvancedPaperSearchView(BaseView):
    form_base_class = FlaskForm

    def __init__(self,
                 name=None,
                 category=None,
                 endpoint=None,
                 url=None,
                 template='auth/model/paper/advanced_search.html',
                 menu_class_name=None,
                 menu_icon_type=None,
                 menu_icon_value=None
                 ):
        super(AdvancedPaperSearchView, self).__init__(
            name,
            category,
            endpoint,
            url or '/',
            'static',
            menu_class_name=menu_class_name,
            menu_icon_type=menu_icon_type,
            menu_icon_value=menu_icon_value)
        self._template = template

    def is_visible(self):
        return False

    def is_accessible(self):
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            return current_user.can_view_papers()

        return False

    @expose('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index(self):
        form = PaperSearchForm()
        form.return_url.data = request.args['return_url']
        self._template_args['form'] = form
        self._template_args['cancel_url'] = request.args['return_url']
        return self.render(self._template)

    @expose('/search', methods=['POST'])
    def search(self):
        # List view generates list of models based on 'term'= from request.args.get('term', default=None)
        # Manually setting these arguments will serve as the advanced search functionality
        form = PaperSearchForm()  # ???
        search = None  # ??? 
        filter = None  # ???
        flash('How to apply multiple filters?', 'error')

        return redirect('papermodelview.index', search=search, filter=filter)  # ???
```

Then, the template is defined like this:

```
{% extends "admin/master.html" %}
{% import 'admin/lib.html' as lib with context %}
{% from 'admin/lib.html' import extra with context %} {# backward compatible #}
{% from 'admin/lib.html' import render_field with context %}

{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    {{ lib.form_css() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    {% block navlinks %}
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li>
            <a href="{{ return_url }}">List</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Advanced Search</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    {% endblock %}

    <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('advancedpapersearchview.search') }}">
        {{ form.return_url }}
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ render_field(form, form.title) }}
        {{ render_field(form, form.abstract) }}
        {{ render_field(form, form.start_date) }}
        {{ render_field(form, form.end_date) }}
        {{ render_field(form, form.doi) }}
        {{ render_field(form, form.pubmed_id) }}
        {{ render_field(form, form.link) }}
        {{ render_field(form, form.journals) }}
        {{ render_field(form, form.authors) }}
        {{ render_field(form, form.chapters) }}
        {{ render_field(form, form.keywords) }}
        {{ render_field(form, form.printed) }}
        {{ render_field(form, form.unprinted) }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn") }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <a href="{{ cancel_url }}" class="btn warning">
                    Cancel
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}

{% block tail %}
    {{ super() }}
    {{ lib.form_js() }}
    <script src="/static/vendor/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">/script>
     {# use /static/bootstrap2/js/bootstrap.min.js if you are using bootstrap2 #}
     <script src="/static/bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/static/vendor/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/static/vendor/select2/select2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

In the Paper Model View, the filters are defined like this:

```
class PaperModelView(MainModelView):
    # ...
        column_filters = [
        'chapter_paper_assoc.printed',
        'journal_paper_assoc.publication_date',
        'chapters.name',
        'chapters.number',
        'journals.name',
        'authors.last_name',
        'keywords.keyword',
    ]
```

So, I commented a bunch of ??? where I don't know what to do. How do I map the fields of my form (specific attributes of the models selected) to the filters that are defined by 'column_filters' in the model view.

I.e -- rather than overriding the index view search handling to actually perform a search, I could instead apply a bunch of filters by passing this information to the index view, which retrieves this information with:

```
filters=response.args.get('filter', None)
```

Is there a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, things are about to get ugly, so hold onto your hat.

This is what I ended up writing to accomplish this functionality, and it is code that I am not particularly proud to have written. It works, but that said, please suggest a cleaner way to do this if you feel like it.

Here is the advanced search view:

```
from flask import flash
from flask import redirect
from flask import request
from flask import url_for
from flask_admin import BaseView
from flask_admin import expose
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_login import current_user
from app import admin
from .forms import PaperSearchForm


class AdvancedPaperSearchView(BaseView):
    form_base_class = FlaskForm

    def __init__(self,
                 name=None,
                 category=None,
                 endpoint=None,
                 url=None,
                 template='auth/model/paper/advanced_search.html',
                 menu_class_name=None,
                 menu_icon_type=None,
                 menu_icon_value=None
                 ):
        super(AdvancedPaperSearchView, self).__init__(
            name,
            category,
            endpoint,
            url or '/',
            'static',
            menu_class_name=menu_class_name,
            menu_icon_type=menu_icon_type,
            menu_icon_value=menu_icon_value)
        self._template = template

    def is_visible(self):
        return False

    def is_accessible(self):
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            return current_user.can_view_papers()

        return False

    @expose('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index(self):
        form = PaperSearchForm()
        form.return_url.data = request.args['return_url']
        self._template_args['form'] = form
        self._template_args['cancel_url'] = request.args['return_url']
        return self.render(self._template)

    @expose('/search', methods=['POST'])
    def search(self):
        form = PaperSearchForm()

        # The goal here is to get the paper model view from the currently running app (and its admin extension). Once
        # the model view is here, use it to get the available filters (get their keys and operations). Use the existing
        # request args and add filters to them using the key and operations defined in the model view.
        paper_model_view = None

        for view in admin._views:
            # There must be a better way to do this, and I know this is a WTF, but I don't have the vocabulary to search
            # the flask admin documentation for the right way to get the instance of the model view from the admin
            # object. I need the *instance*, with the filters created and added to that instance by the init... so...
            # not clean or pretty ... and permanently restricts name of paper model view ... TODO: Fix? Rewrite?
            # - Chris, March 2017
            if "PaperModelView object" in view.__repr__():
                paper_model_view = view

        # ._filters contains the list of all  filters
        # ._filter_args contains a dictionary of keys and filter objects for url construction
        # each filter is persisted with request.args, the query string is <flt[position]_[key]=[value]> or
        # <flt[position]_[key]> for filters without values
        # The filter is accessed by looking up the filter object with the key value, and then the filters are listed
        # in the order of the position provided in the query string. I am unsure whether or not they are applied in
        # this order, but that seems like what is happening.
        filters = {}
        i = 0
        str = "flt{pos}_{key}"

        def __check(column, table, filter):
            return (column in filter.column.name and table in filter.column.table.name.__repr__())

        # Sorry for this...
        # Iterate through each filter available for the view. Check if it's name and operation are something that
        # will enact a portion of the search, then add it's filter (in the format expected) to a dictionary. The index
        # variable i keeps track of the "count" of filters that have been added and uses this as the position of the
        # filter.
        for key, key_filter in paper_model_view._filter_args.items():
            filter = key_filter[1]
            if hasattr(filter, 'column'):
                if __check("title", "papers", filter):
                    if "FilterLike" in filter.operation.__repr__():
                        if form.title.data:
                            filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = form.title.data
                            i += 1
                if __check("abstract", "papers", filter):
                    if "FilterLike" in filter.operation.__repr__():
                        if form.abstract.data:
                            filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = form.abstract.data
                            i += 1
                if __check("publication_date", "journal_paper", filter):
                    if "DateSmaller" in filter.operation.__repr__():
                        if form.end_date.data:
                            filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = form.end_date.data.date()  # Only keeps the date for the filter
                            i += 1
                    elif "DateGreater" in filter.operation.__repr__():
                        if form.start_date.data:
                            filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = form.start_date.data.date()
                            i += 1
                if __check("doi", "papers", filter):
                    if "FilterLike" in filter.operation.__repr__():
                        if form.doi.data:
                            filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = form.doi.data
                            i += 1
                if __check("pubmed_id", "papers", filter):
                    if "FilterLike" in filter.operation.__repr__():
                        if form.pubmed_id.data:
                            filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = form.pubmed_id.data
                            i += 1
                if __check("link", "papers", filter):
                    if "FilterLike" in filter.operation.__repr__():
                        if form.link.data:
                            filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = form.link.data
                            i += 1
                if __check("name", "journal", filter):
                    if "FilterLike" in filter.operation.__repr__():
                        if form.journals.data:
                            for journal in form.journals.data:
                                filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = journal.name
                                i += 1
                if __check("first_name", "authors", filter):
                    if "FilterLike" in filter.operation.__repr__():
                        for author in form.authors.data:
                            filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = author.first_name
                            i += 1
                if __check("last_name", "authors", filter):
                    if "FilterLike" in filter.operation.__repr__():
                        for author in form.authors.data:
                            filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = author.last_name
                            i += 1
                if __check("keyword", "keywords", filter):
                    if "FilterLike" in filter.operation.__repr__():
                        for keyword in form.keywords.data:
                            filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = keyword.keyword
                            i += 1
                if __check("name", "chapters", filter):
                    if "FilterLike" in filter.operation.__repr__():
                        for chapter in form.chapters.data:
                            filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = chapter.name
                            i += 1
                if __check("printed", "chapter_paper", filter):
                    if "FilterEqual" in filter.operation.__repr__():
                        if form.printed.data == True:
                            if form.unprinted.data == False:  # Printed only
                                filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = 1  # True
                                i += 1
                            else:
                                pass # Both are True
                        else:
                            if form.unprinted.data == True:  # Unprinted only
                                filters[str.format(pos=i, key=key)] = 0  # False
                                i += 1
                            else:
                                pass # Both are False

                else:
                    continue

        flash('Filters successfully applied', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('paper.index_view', **filters))
```